# Create a pandas dataframe with the number of rides by hour and user type for workdays and weekends

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Create a pandas DataFrame with the number of rides by Hour and User Type for Workdays and Weekends. Use starttime to determine each ride's hour. Here is the CSV file from where starttime will come
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KXs5bh3CmPWXJkQWhkbzI0WEE/view?usp=sharing
Data must be in this form
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiWl2.png)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer':rides['starttime']})
rides['Customer'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Customer'])
df['User Type Hour'] = rides['Customer'].dt.hour
df2=df[rides['usertype']=="Customer"].groupby('User Type Hour').count()
df2
df5 = pd.DataFrame({'Subscriber':rides['starttime']})
rides['Subscriber'] = pd.to_datetime(df5['Subscriber'])
df5['User Type Hour'] = rides['Subscriber'].dt.hour
dfe=df5[rides['usertype']=="Subscriber"].groupby('User Type Hour').count()
dfe
#c= df2.style.set_table_styles([dict(selector="th",props=[('max-width', '100px')])])
frames=[df2,dfe]
#concatinate the dataframes
result=pd.concat(frames, axis=1, join='inner')
result
```

here is the code by which i calculated hours for whole week(mon-sun).
i searched various post and found

```
df.index.dayofweek >= 5
```

but didn't get the result.
small size of CSV [File Link][2]

Comment: Hmm... I can't seem to download the file. Can you provide about 20 rows of data here?

Comment: ohk sure i gonna copy paste some columns

Comment: Edited the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

- add parameter `parse_dates` for convert columns to datetime
- create new Series by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for `type`s
- create new Series by [`hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html)
- [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `types`, `hours` and by `usertype`, aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html)

---

```
df = pd.read_csv('201507-citibike-tripdata.csv', parse_dates=[1,2])

types = np.where(df['starttime'].dt.dayofweek >= 5, 'Weekends', 'Workdays')
hours = df['starttime'].dt.hour
result = df.groupby([types, hours, 'usertype']).size().unstack()
```

---

```
print (result)


usertype            Customer  Subscriber
         starttime                      
Weekends 0              1079        3184
         1               609        2192
         2               429        1410
         ...
         21             2411        6207
         22             2192        5083
         23             1463        3555
Workdays 0              1385        6075
         1               768        2850
         2               442        1472
         ...
         23             2611       12607
```

Some data cleaning:

```
df = df.reset_index() \
       .rename_axis(None, 1) \
       .rename(columns={'level_0':'type', 'starttime':'User Type Hour'})
print (df)

        type  User Type Hour  Customer  Subscriber
0   Weekends               0      1079        3184
1   Weekends               1       609        2192
...
23  Weekends              23      1463        3555
24  Workdays               0      1385        6075
25  Workdays               1       768        2850
...
46  Workdays              22      3311       19137
47  Workdays              23      2611       12607
```

If need omit values in `type` column:

```
df = df.reset_index() \
       .rename_axis(None, 1) \
       .rename(columns={'level_0':'type', 'starttime':'User Type Hour'})

df['type'] = df['type'].mask(df['type'].duplicated(), '')
print (df)

        type  User Type Hour  Customer  Subscriber
0   Weekends               0      1079        3184
1                          1       609        2192
2                          2       429        1410
...
22                        22      2192        5083
23                        23      1463        3555
24  Workdays               0      1385        6075
25                         1       768        2850
26                         2       442        1472
...
46                        22      3311       19137
47                        23      2611       12607
```

Comment: Not getting the exect result i want the data in that format which is given in the pic

Comment: Sorry, I add second solution for this. Do you need columns only `Customer` and `Subscriber` ?

Comment: on the column name "usertype subscriber" there is "User Type Hour"

Comment: Do you want 4 columns?

Comment: i want this output

Comment: I have no permission to your drive.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KXs5bh3CmPZlRKUTlfWG04cDA/view?usp=sharing    format link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KXs5bh3CmPWXJkQWhkbzI0WEE/view?usp=sharing     small CSV file

Comment: Sure, but first column is index of dataframe or column of dataframe?

Comment: If need omit values in types, it cannot be `index`, only columns. Check edited answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153839/discussion-between-nitikesh-and-jezrael).